# How to read data sent to app-measurement from firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I'm trying to do a network analysis of an Android app to see what information Firebase is collecting. I'm doing a man-in-the-middle using Fiddler and can observe pings to Firebase's app-measurement server. But when I decrypt the content to try to see what's being passed, it looks like the message is encoded or compressed somehow. The messages look like this when opened in a text editor:

```
POST https://app-measurement.com/a HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 761
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; Google Nexus 6 Build/LMY47D)
Host: app-measurement.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


öR

_c


_oauto

_r

_pfo 

_sys 

_uwa 
    
_sysu _fÎž¶Þ.  "


_oauto

_et_eÎž¶Þ.  D

_si¹þ½‚ÌÓ¹¨_vsÓëž¶Þ. ÎÏž¶Þ.Îž¶Þ._fot €ºÀ¶Þ.Îž¶Þ._fi ³Ÿ¶Þ._lte œ ²Ÿ¶Þ.(Îž¶Þ.0Óëž¶Þ.BandroidJ5.1RGoogle Nexus 6Zen-us`Ôýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿjmanual_installr<my-app-bundle-name>‚4.6.19166.0322ˆÄwÄwª <text here>°ñÊîüƒÝÏÊ¸Ê'1:849883241272:android:<my-aaid> òdVZyNR1YbAMøºç’1d5adf7b1442fe22˜ŽºªÜàÙè  ð
```

Is anyone familiar with this encoding? How can I decode to view the raw text? I've tried gzip, but that doesn't seem to be it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not compressed or really obfuscated in any way.   You can see plaintext data right there in the payload if you look carefully.  What you're capturing is almost certainly a [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) in binary form, and you'll have to get a hold of the protobuf definition in order to decode it without putting in the work to reverse engineer it.  That's not something Google discloses for API endpoints that are not publicly documented.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I see the plaintext but was just worried I might be missing information that's currently binary. I'm not very familiar with protobuf but will look into how to reverse engineer the definition (unless that's something that's super challenging)